# how to style php echo table

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following code and I would like to style it. Are there any ways to do this?

Specifically I want to center the Columns headings and the text within each cell.

```
echo "Variable Profile";
echo "<table>";
echo "<th>"."STATE"."</th>";
echo "<th>"."$column_name"."</th>";

foreach($lotsofasians as $lotsofasian){
echo "<tr>";

echo "<td>".$lotsofasian->state."</td>";
echo "<td>".$lotsofasian->$column_selected."</td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

I have tried putting something like align= 'center' in the  tag but I cant get it to work.

Comment: @AmalMurali they should use CSS, not deprecated attributes like `align`

Comment: @celeriko: That's not what I actually wanted to say -- deleted the comment as it promotes a bad practice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using css rather than using inline styles
css

```
table th,table td{
 text-align:center;
}
```

See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aSnUB/)

Comment: Where would I put this? before the table?

Comment: @grad_student do you know what css is??

Answer (score 1):

With regard to styling HTML, there's nothing special about the fact that PHP is outputting it. You can still give your elements classes, IDs, inline styling or whatever - it's just that if PHP is involved you'll have to reference these in the `echo` output statements.

Just change the `echo` statement to include classes as required, e.g.

`echo "<table class='some_class'>";`

Answer (score 0):

Your php is going to output something like this:

```
<table>
<th>state value</th>
<th>column value</th>
<tr>
<td>value</td>
<td>value</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I would sneak a `<tr>` in there for your `<th>` elements as well:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th></th>
</tr>
```

Then, create some css rules:

```
table th, table td { padding: 5px; text-align: center; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use css-classes or inline styles.

Why you quote Variables? Your HTML is not valid.

simplest way:

```
echo 'Variable Profile';
printf('<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>%s</th>
                <th>%s</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>', 'State', $column_name);

        foreach($lotsofasians AS $index => $lotsofasian) {
            $style = array();

            /* Example 1: center text */
            $style[] = 'text-align: center;';

            /* Example 2: Set Background each second output */
            if($index % 2 == 0) {
                $style[] = 'background: #DDDDDD;';
            }

            printf('<tr style="%">
                        <td>%s</td>
                        <td>%s</td>
                    </tr>', implode('', $style), $lotsofasian->state, $lotsofasian->{$column_selected});
        }
echo '</tbody>
    </table>';
```